# Need to transpose Rows into Columns using WPDataTables to query MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress Plugin that allows me to pull data out from my WordPress DB. Problem is that the DB is created by a forms plugin and the table structure is fixed:

```
+--------------+------------------+
|Column        |Type              |
+--------------+------------------+
|submit_time   |decimal(16,4)     |
+--------------+------------------+
|form_name     |varchar(127) NULL |
+--------------+------------------+
|field_name    |varchar(127) NULL |
+--------------+------------------+
|field_value   |longtext NULL     |
+--------------+------------------+
|field_order   |int(11) NULL      |
+--------------+------------------+
|file          |longblob NULL     |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Therefore the values that appear in the DB is not ideal for reading or editing.

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|submit_time |form_name   |field_name       | field_value      |file_order  |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |your-name        | Leonard Chia     |9999        |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |your-email       | leonard@mail     |8           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |status           | Pending Start    |9           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |location         | DD1 Classroom    |7           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
```

I was trying to achieve this:

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Requestor   | Email       | Location      | Status        |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|Leonard Chia | leonard@mail| DD1 Classroom | Pending Start |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|Sng Yeekia   | yeekias@mail| DD2 Classroom | Pending Spare |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|Gabriel Lee  | gabriel@mail| SL1 Classroom | Completed     |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I tried to transpose or pivot the tables using `CASE WHEN IF` but it doesn't work. Also tried to use `MAX` and `UNION ALL`but same results.

Can anyone here point out to me what's wrong with my coding?

This is my code:

```
SELECT wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.submit_time
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'your-name', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Requestor,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'campus', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Campus,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'location', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Defect Location,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'your-message', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Defect Description,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'menu-priority', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Priority,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'work-done', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Action Taken,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'assigned-to', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Assigned To,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'category', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Category,
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'file-photo', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Photo
   MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'status', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value,NULL)) AS Status
FROM wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.submit_time
```

The error returned from wpdatatables:

> No results found. Please check if this query is correct! Table Constructor needs a query that returns data to build a wpDataTable.
>   Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX (IF(wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'your-name', wpc5_cf7dbplugin_subm' at line 1

***Update***

Edited the code to below

```
    SELECT wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.submit_time,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'your-name' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Requestor,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'campus' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Campus,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'location' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Location,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'your-message' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Description,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'menu-priority' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Priority,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'work-done' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Action,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'assigned-to' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Assigned,
   CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'category' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Category,
  CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'file-photo' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Photo,
  CASE WHEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_name = 'status' THEN wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.field_value ELSE NULL END AS Status
FROM wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits.submit_time
```

The table had more NULL then fields, most of the filled up fields are only from the 1st column, which is rather weird.

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Requestor   | Campus   | Location | Status   |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
|Leonard Chia | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
|NULL         | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
|Gabriel Lee  | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

What has gone wrong??

Comment: The bigger problem is what's wrong with your question.  You gave a link to a collection of garbled, difficult to read, screen captures.  Instead, edit your question and show sample table input and the output you expect.

Comment: have edited, sorry it was my first time posting and they limited me to only 1 photo link.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `submit_time` and also the alias `Photo`.  Other than this your query looks fine.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I did the amendments, together with changing the text after AS to a single word, the error came back as:

`Error in query (1630): FUNCTION sjckorg_wp385.MAX does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

Comment: I fixed your syntax errors, q.v. my answer below.  You can't have a space after `MAX` (to my own surprise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query looked correct to me so I decided to test it in the following demo:

## Demo

I found two problems which were causing compiler errors:

1. You were using aliases consisting of two words but you weren't escaping them.  Instead of using `AS Defect Location` put backticks around the words comprising the alias: `` AS `Defect Location` ``
2. Your query put space in between `MAX` and the opening parenthesis, e.g. `MAX (IF(condition, ...)`.  To my surprise, when I removed this space the query started working.

Here is your original query with these errors corrected:

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS Requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'campus',        field_value, NULL)) AS Campus,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS `Defect Location`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-message',  field_value, NULL)) AS `Defect Description`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-priority', field_value, NULL)) AS Priority,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'work-done',     field_value, NULL)) AS `Action Taken`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'assigned-to',   field_value, NULL)) AS `Assigned To`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'category',      field_value, NULL)) AS Category,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'file-photo',    field_value, NULL)) AS Photo
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'status',        field_value, NULL)) AS Status
FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

Note that you don't need to repeat the full table name when querying a single table.

Comment: Awesome! But 3 columns are not displaying: `Campus`, `Action Taken` and `Status`. I found that a comma is missing after `Photo` but other than that, i can't find anything else that is causing the columns to have empty fields.

Comment: It's fully working now! Thank you so much for your time to solve syntax errors. Appreciate the effort!

Comment: It was the naming, `campus` should've been `menu-campus`, `work-done` = `work_done` and as for the `status`, the table was trying to display it as int instead of string. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Done! But I have another question... When i try to edit the fields on the frontpage, there seems to be an error passing the values back into the fields in the DB. Now, the columns are named `Requestor` `Status` etc. But the DB don't recognizes theses as columns, what can I do now?

Comment: I don't know WP well enough to completely follow your new problem, but maybe you can change the aliases in my query to something different which will work.

Comment: The error returned was `ERROR Unknown column 'Requestor' from the field_list` I'm guessing that when the change was made, the system cannot find column name 'Requestor' etc. since we've pivoted everything....

Comment: @leoccl You might want to post a follow-up question, and give it several Wordpress tags.

Comment: I just did! Thanks for all you help so far! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292479/update-pivoted-table-to-db