# UPDATE pivoted table to DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, datatables

I have a pivoted table from a MySQL query that was derived from:

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|submit_time |form_name   |field_name       | field_value      |file_order  |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |your-name        | Leonard Chia     |9999        |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |your-email       | leonard@mail     |8           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |status           | Pending Start    |9           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|15052703120 |Submissions |location         | DD1 Classroom    |7           |file | 
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----+
```

to this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------+---------------+
| Requestor   | Email       |ETC. |Location      | Status        |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------+---------------+
|Leonard Chia | leonard@mail|ETC. |DD1 Classroom | Pending Start |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------+---------------+
|Sng Yeekia   | yeekias@mail|ETC. |DD2 Classroom | Pending Spare |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------+---------------+
|Gabriel Lee  | gabriel@mail|ETC. |SL1 Classroom | Completed     |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------+---------------+
```

The table is achieved using a wpDataTables plugin which provides me a shortcode for the table to be displayed on my webpage. The query used to extract the data is as such:

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS Requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'campus',        field_value, NULL)) AS Campus,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS `Defect Location`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-message',  field_value, NULL)) AS `Defect Description`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-priority', field_value, NULL)) AS Priority,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'work-done',     field_value, NULL)) AS `Action Taken`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'assigned-to',   field_value, NULL)) AS `Assigned To`,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'category',      field_value, NULL)) AS Category,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'file-photo',    field_value, NULL)) AS Photo
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'status',        field_value, NULL)) AS Status
FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

The plugin allows users to edit the table in the frontend. Issue comes when I tried to edit any value on the table via the frontend table, there is an error prompted and values are not updated.

The error returned is `ERROR Unknown column 'Requestor' from the field_list`. I'm guessing that the DB doesn't recognize the column headers since they've been pivoted.

Am seeking for ideas or workarounds on how I can solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Who or what is consuming the output from your (correctly functioning) pivot query?  If it doesn't expect a column named `Requestor`, then what does it actually expect?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it expects 'field_name' instead

Comment: Well you could of course alias `Requestor` to `field_name`, but you can't do that for every column in your query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly! when i changed `Requestor` and the rest to `field_name`, the tables came out to be like the initial one. Bummer...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you think it's workable if i save this queried table as a new db and then get the wpDataTables to read/udate on the new db instead?

Comment: any ways to save this queried table as a new db?

Comment: Do you want a new _database_ or a new _table_?

Comment: I believe new DB.
Could I run the query as such:

`IF NOT EXIST CREATE TABLE edit_mdr ELSE INSERT INTO edit_mdr
SELECT
    submit_time,
   
    MAX(IF( ..., NULL)) AS ...,

FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time`

But this will this overwrite any pre-existing data or append duplicated data everytime it loads?

Comment: I don't know enough about WordPress to follow your issue.

Comment: I don't know the solution to this, but from SQL documentation, I believe updating doesn't work because it uses aggregate functions, in this case, MAX.